# How to determine the correct constraint violation on SQLite UpdateException?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, try-catch, updateexception

I have the following problem qith my local SQLite database. I'm trying to update the data stored via a synchronisation-process with an online SQL-Server database.
While there is no problem with the synchonization I often encounter errors when trying to update the local values.
E.g. there can be an violation with existing Primary-Key-Constraints on each table. On the other hand there could also be a violation of the Unique-Key on a concrete table.

My question is how to figure out which type of error occured.

I catch the database update or insert like

```
catch(UpdateException ue)
{
    HandleUpdateException(ue);
}
```

The handle method is as follows:

```
private void HandleUpdateException(UpdateException e)
{
    // get inner exception as SQLiteException
    var innerException = e.InnerException as SQLiteException;

    if(innerException != null)
    {
        switch(innerException.ErrorCode)
        {
            case SQLiteError.Constraint:
                // handle constraint-error here
                break;
            default:
                // log error
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I now which error occured? It's important to know because the handling of PK-violation is completely other than a UK-violation.

I could try to make

```
if(e.Message.Contains("unique")) // ...
```

or

```
if(e.Message.Contains("foreign")) // ...
```

but I don't like to check with "magic" strings for the kind of error.

So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The information you want will likely only be contained in the message.  You could purposely cause an exception, then in a debugger inspect the exception to see if there are better values that you could check.  Also, I would recommend doing String.IndexOf("unique", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0  due ot case issues.

Comment: I already checked the other values contained in the UpdateException and also the SQLiteException. But both (PK and UK violations) are handled under Constraint-Error which is not wrong at all, but not enough information.

Comment: That is what I figured.  Sorry, but it looks like you will have to parse the message property for the specific exception type that you want to handle.  Good luck.

Comment: Ok. Not the best way but obviously the only thing that will work. Thanks anyway for your help